# Perl: test for an arbitrary bit in a bit string

Tags: perl

I'm trying to parse CPU node affinity+cache sibling info in Linyx sysfs.

I can get a string of bits, just for example:

`0000111100001111`

Now I need a function where I have a decimal number (e.g. 4 or 5) and I need to test whether the nth bit is set or not. So it would return `true` for `4` and `false` for `5`. I could create a string by shifting `1` n number of times, but I'm not sure about the syntax, and is there an easier way? Also, there's no limit on how long the string could be, so I want to avoid decimal <-> binary conversoins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have the string of bits "0000111100001111" in `$str`, if you do the precomputation step:

```
my $bit_vector = pack "b*", $str;
```

you can then use [vec](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/vec.html) like so:

```
$is_set = vec $bit_vector, $offset, 1;
```

so for example, this code

```
for (0..15) {
  print "$_\n" if vec $bit_vector, $_, 1;
}
```

will output

```
4
5
6
7
12
13
14
15
```

Note that the offsets are zero-based, so if you want the first bit to be bit 1, you'll need to add/subtract 1 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems to work, and I'm not going for efficiency:

```
sub is_bit_set
{
        my $bitstring = shift;
        my $bit = shift;

        my $index = length($bitstring) - $bit - 1;
        if (substr($bitstring, $index, 1) == "1") {
                return 1;
        }
        else {
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler variant without bit vector, but for sure vector would be more efficient way to deal.

```
sub is_bit_set
{
        my $bitstring = shift;
        my $bit = shift;
        return int substr($bitstring, -$bit, 1);
}
```